# Get count for all terms inside a parent term

Tags: terms, hierarchical, children

I am trying to get the post count for a term and it's child terms. I tried it with `pad_count=> true` but this seems to have no effect.

My term stucture is like the following:

```
- term 1: 10 posts
- term 2: 1 post
  -- subterm 1: 4 posts
  -- subterm 2: 12 posts
- term 3: 4 posts
```

This is my code:

```
$args = array(
  'pad_counts' => true
);
$terms = get_terms('category', $args);
foreach($terms as $term) {
  var_dump( $term->count );
}
```

For all the terms without children this works just fine, but for the "term 2", I want to get the counts of itself and it's children combined. In my example this would be 17. The code only gives me 1, though.

Any Tips?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that code didn't work for you. I copy that code and it work exactly as I expected. You should double check your case, did you unset `$args` variable before, or you can use another name ($agrs2 for example).

Another problem in you question is: if `pad_counts` doesn't work, you will get 1 not 3.

Comment: oh you are right, I ment 1 of course. I will double check my code and report back.